ImportError: cannot import name 'pkg_resources' from 'ydata_profiling'
I am new to streamlit and I am trying to use the ydata_profiling library for AutoML, but I keep getting the error of ImportError: cannot import name 'pkg_resources' from 'ydata_profiling'.
I tried reinstalling the ydata_profiling library and I also cleared the cache from VS Code, still I am getting the same error.
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 600, in _run_script
exec(code, module.dict)
File "C:\Users\harsh\Downloads\Auto ML\app.py", line 5, in 
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport, pkg_resources
And I also upgraded the setuptools still I am getting the same error.
The project I am working on is very exciting, I dont want to leave it please help!!!
I used the ydata_profiling library in streamlit in my application and I got error, so I uninstalled and reinstalled the ydata_profiling library, upgraded the setuptools which might contain the pkg_resources name and also cleared the cache from VS Code and I expected to not get the error afterwards
